# Filter from key value objects in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, key-value

I am creating searchbar to filter key value data objects. I am getting filter is not a function error while doing search. Is there any other function to filter in key value pair objects ?

Data :-

```
{
  meta_city : {
    label: "City"
    values: (5) ["DL", "KA", "GJ", "MH", "UP"]
   },
  meta_country : {
    label: "Country"
    values: (5) ["IN", "US", "CA"]
   }
}
```

Handle search (filterData data is local state) :-

```
const handleSearchFilter = (event) => {
    const searchWord = event.target.value;
    const newFilter = Object.keys(filterData).map((key) => {
      filterData[key].filter((value) => {
        return value.includes(searchWord);
      });
    });
    setFilterData(newFilter);
  };
```

```
<div className="mp-input-field-container">
     <input
       className="mp-input"
       placeholder="Search"
       onChange={handleSearchFilter}                    
     />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter according to the `values` field of item in the object?

Comment: @gilamran yes ..

Comment: What are you expecting the result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `reduce` like this:

```
const handleSearchFilter = (event) => {
  const searchWord = event.target.value;
  const newFilter = Object.keys(filterData).reduce((result, key) => {
    if (filterData[key].values.includes(searchWord)) {
      result.push(filterData[key]);
    };
    return result;
  }, []);
  setFilterData(newFilter);
};
```

In this example I'm returning an array result. you can return an object if you want.

Comment: it is giving this error > TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: I think reduce is overkill in this situation. Add a "?." before "includes" to handle the case there is an entry without the "values" property. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Filter does not exist on a string type. When filterData[key] is called, key has a value of `label`. filterData["label"] returns a string "City".

try

```
const searchWord = (word) => Object.values(filterData).filter((data) => data.values?.includes(word));

const handleSearchFilter = (event) => {
  const word = event.target.value;
  const [newFilter] = searchWord(word)
  setFilterData(newFilter);
}
```

searchWord returns if you search "DL"

```
[
  {
    label: 'City',
    values: [ 'DL', 'KA', 'GJ', 'MH', 'UP' ]
  }
]
```

Was that the result you were looking for?

Here is the code snippet to prove the solution works:

```js
var filterData = {
  meta_city : {
    label: "City",
    values: ["DL", "KA", "GJ", "MH", "UP"]
   },
  meta_country : {
    label: "Country",
    values: ["IN", "US", "CA"]
   }
}


const searchWord = (word) => Object.values(filterData).filter((data) => data.values.includes(word));


console.log(searchWord("DL"))
```

Comment: how can i update the state after this ? I mean filterData is an local state

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry I thought that was obvious

Comment: Your solution returns an array of words, not results...

Comment: yes .. it returns nothing ...

Comment: @fredericrous TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: searchWord is returning an array of results. newFilter extracts the first entry of the array

Comment: @Gurupal you are facing a different issue. I can't debug your code for you. I included a code snippet that you can run to prove my code works.

Comment: @fredericrous your solution works .. i tested it .. but on typing it shows undefined or null object

Comment: im no typescript guru. you could try something like ```const searchWord : [{
    label:string,
    values: string[]
   }]  = (word: string) => {
    return Object.values(filterData).filter((data) => data.values.includes(word))
  };
```